# MiKTeX Package installation does not work on-the-fly, but works manually via MiKTeX Console

Tags: miktex, installing

I just installed MiKTeX and TeXstudio and tried to compile a finished document with lots of different packages. When I installed MiKTeX, I set the option to `always install missing packages on-the-fly` and also confirmed it in the settings of the MiKTeX Console.

Sadly, I always get the same error :

> `Unfortunately, the package koma-script could not be installed. Please check
>   the log file:
>   C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/MiKTeX/2.9/miktex/log/pdflatex.log`

I this logfile I found this entry:

> `2019-01-15 10:43:09,851+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Permission denied:
>   C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Temp/hl9040.tex`
>
> `2019-01-15 10:43:09,851+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Info:
>   C:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/Temp/hl9040.tex`
>
> `2019-01-15 10:43:09,851+0100 FATAL pdflatex - Source:
>   Libraries\MiKTeX\Core\win\winFile.cpp`

So, apparently some permissions are getting denied, although I already tried running the MiKTeX Console and TeXstudio as admin.

If I try to Install packages directly via the MiKTeX Console, everything works fine. I can just search for the missing package and it gets installed succesfully. After that, I get a new message telling me the next package is missing.

**Additional Info:** Everytime I open the MiKTeX Console, it tells me that there's a PATH issue and asks if I want to fix it now. But if confirm fixing it, the same message pops up, when I open it again. I don't know, if that is part of the problem, but I assume it.

## Edit: (added comment):

I tried to execute the installation file as an administrator and it seems to work now! After Installing it I tried to compile my file again and got a new error report:

> ```
> commando crashed: pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode "FileName".tex.
> ```

I tried googling it but couldn't find anything.  I did install everything and ran everything as admin now and uninstalled everything before ...

Comment: Did you log on as Name?

Comment: @JohnKormylo No, I just didn't want to write my private username in here :)

Comment: Also, after you uninstall the old version you need to delete everything.  If you have a registry cleaner, use it.